# Array Rotation with $_session for All user

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, session, rotation

When a file is accessed it will appear ***1***, as refreshes appear ***2***, and in refrest reappeared ***3***, and so on.

I use $_SESSION but when it's applied rotation different array in each user/browser,

I want when user A accessing the php file appear ***1***, 
and when the user A re-access (refresh) the file will display ***2***, user B accessing result ***3*** and so on up to a maximum value then spun repeat from the beginning. all the user to continue the rotation instead of repeating each.

```
<?php
session_start();
$value = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10');
if(!isset($_SESSION['no'])||$_SESSION['no']==count($value)-1){
$_SESSION['no'] = 0;
} else{
$_SESSION['no'] +=1;
}
$value = $value[$_SESSION['no']];
echo $value;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not to use an array?

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['no'])){
  $_SESSION['no'] = 1;
}
elseif($_SESSION['no'] === 10){
  $_SESSION['no'] = 1;
} else {
  $_SESSION['no']++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store this access call in DB (or a file). Session is only specific to each user session. The other option is using like MemCache caching. DB is the best way in my opinion.